# Popular politicians and e-mail hacks

Tags: email

Often, lately, I see e-mail servers hacked. Just recently I've heard of Hillary Clintons personal server being hacked, Turkish diplomatic/government e-mails and the most recent one: the DNC servers / e-mail.

How do these attacks work in general? What is to blame?

EDIT: A lot of these attack are said to be state-sponsored. What exactly gives any state advantage in securing or breaking something as simple as e-mail in comparison to civilian security companies?

Comment: Clinton's server did NOT get hacked, the DNC's did. @GeorgeBailey: that's not what the FBI was investigating...

Comment: You're right, that's not exactly what the FBI was investigating, but it was part of the investigation. From [the official statement](https://www.fbi.gov/news/pressrel/press-releases/statement-by-fbi-director-james-b-comey-on-the-investigation-of-secretary-hillary-clinton2019s-use-of-a-personal-e-mail-system) *"given the nature of the system and of the actors potentially involved, we assess that we would be unlikely to see such direct evidence. ... we assess it is possible that hostile actors gained access to Secretary Clinton’s personal e-mail account"*

Comment: @dandavis Secretary of State Clintons email did get hacked

Comment: It is only their stupidity to blame. In most cases, they have too easy passwords so practically any kid with some spare time can guess them. Those are not hacks. The state-sponsored (or mostly corporate-sponsored) ones are an entirely different subject. Yes, these happen often, but usually you won't see that in the news.

Comment: @Ramhound: breaking big news? got a link to a reputable source confirming that hack? "did"!="is possible"

Answer (score 2):

The reason why it is occurring is inappropriate defense.
If you run organization which is frequently targeted by hackers you need to take some minimum precautions:

- Have all systems updated (e.g. Windows Update, Chrome update etc, switch/router update, VPN etc)
- All traffic inspected on firewalls
- Have monitoring of all networks and systems for bandwidth and flows
- Established procedures what to do in case of breach
- Strict access and password policies
- Employ Smart Cards for identification (as these are harder to steal than passwords)
- Have intrusion detection systems in cloud
- Run Antivirus on desktops
- Mandatory Access Control on servers
- If the infrastructure is automated, being able to quickly patch and re-deploy changes to fix issues
- Physical security for systems like authentication servers, source code, databases, emails, so for example, multiple clouds so when one is cracked, not everything is compromised
- Encrypted transfers of data and encrypted storage (for sniffing out traffic and stealing the drives)
- Appropriate training of all staff against social engineering
- Good group policy for the desktops, like disable USB sticks
- Good WiFi security including physical security and shielding from outside
- Automated penetration testing (Nessus, OpenVAS scanning)
- Automated brute-force for passwords, keys
- Automated network discovery in network management software
- Good control of what can be connected to the physical / wifi network
- Trusted, verified kernels
- Trusted, verified userspace software
- Separation of network segments
- Aggregate reporting from security systems
- Hardened phones, laptops
- Secure and segregated parking slots, especially in big cities (you know that car parked in front of your company door?)
- Sound-proof cubicles and meeting rooms (it's rarely standard)
- Anti-spying windows
- Drone defense system
- Secure printers, printing policy and document handling policy
- Shoulder sniffing policy
- Harden, harden, harden - EMET etc

What you need to understand, that hacking teams have similar things on their own. They can bypass IDS, they will monitor your networks, they have automated tools to act upon opportunity.

The above is not really difficult to implement. In fact, most are today standard features and it's really easy to do. For a network of 1.000 devices it can be done by typical experienced sysadmin who is not lazy, and if there's good change management process established which is "not taking out the risk by preventing change", which is major and frequent mistake. Especially if info sec team is proud to be working for famous company and not doing much except for self-gratification - it is also serious and frequent problem - that when they need to do change, they actually always fail as they are not aware of how things are working and sticking to some simple ways of working like just adding new devices.

While leaving the door truly open, you can get hacked within seconds. However, if you are targeted, your systems might get compromised and:
  - It may take long to detect it
  - Once hackers understand the network and systems, it may be very difficult to get rid of them

Also, if it's state-sponsored attack you can expect hacks which are not known to public, and may be unknown for long time.

So for sites similar to White-House, basically it could be some sort of problem with change management which is common in state organizations which do "protect" the current order (no matter what is it, it's just psychology), like "we will be secure if we keep things intact". And that "we do not need all updates because they break things" (which is not true today). And people in charge are very often adjusted to such thinking. That's why serious help from proper commercial organization might be invaluable for revival, and sometimes necessary. Another bit is to have security team who is actively defending the systems by reading reports from IDS, Monitoring and so on, writing scripts to automate things and "knowing  their stuff".

The thing is, that high-profile institutions might not get hacked because nobody seriously tried for long time so there was no defense in place. But once you are target of state-sponsored attacks, and possibly from one or more countries the above list is what will keep them off. And you need to make sure the building security as well. Tail-gating and rouge-hiring is nothing unusual in state-sponsored attacks.

Another factor is management ignorance. Whenever you need help from FBI management might try to do cover-up instead of trying to get help simply because of fear of problems with public relations which is unreasonable.

So, I'd guess it's government institution sociology and secondly the famous place magic, which both lowered defenses.
Government organizations do not have monetary motivation to drive change while they should motivate employees to do so anyway for the sake of real security. "Protecting interests" by keeping it same is just illusion. Once the change management is working (updates etc), the bad employees will have to go away if they can't handle it without causing damage. And the management needs to be educated how to avoid illusionary, over-protective behavior which does not make anything safer, and replaced with people who are not just narrow-minded and lazy but are true people leaders.

Answer (score 1):

> How do these attacks work in general?

You should start by finding out what attack types you are interested in. Perhaps you should narrow your list down to one attack of interest, and give us a link to the article you are looking at which describes the successful attack.

> Who is to blame?

The attacker is always to blame. However, at a certain level the system administrators should be held responsible for negligence.

> Often, lately, I see e-mail servers hacked.

It is difficult to address the 'news in general' that you have seen.
This is not a good question for Stack Exchange.
We work better with specific case studies, or questions with a defined technical scope.

Comment: Wow a lot of condescension... I thought whoever managed these servers was to blame and I'm appalled that infrastructure of this high importance is not guarded better. For what it's worth I was thinking of posting this to skeptics SE but there is no claim to be verified.

Comment: Yes, it is appalling and highly negligent. Sorry if I came off as condescending. However you do seem unfamiliar with some of the rules here on Security Stack Exchange. Questions here are supposed to be specific, but your question was very broad. I'm not familiar with the rules at Skeptics SE.